# WooCommerce: how to change featured (main) image of product, choosing (only) from product gallery images?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have imported my products from a CSV and then, I wanted to change some of the "featured" product image, choosing then from those that were uploaded just at the product images gallery ... and I find that it is not possible (!?)

For example, for some product, an image of the product seen from the back, was uploaded as the main image (the first listed in the CSV) ... while I have in the gallery of the product, an image of it, seen from the front.

Of course, I can change the featured image, by choosing (finding it, at first!) among the 4600+ images that I have uploaded to my media gallery ... but it's not reasonable, when I have to do this on 50+ products!

I SIMPLY need to edit the product and modify the featured image, choosing it from one of the images in the product gallery ... click and "set it as main image" (?)

I think it's not a very crazy option ... and in fact, it seems so basic and stupid to me, that I can't imagine it not being considered in WooCommerce!
So, I think it's just me, who can't find the option ... a way to do it!

Any idea to guide me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The only (faster) way is to re-import a .csv file with the "Images" field valued as the following file:

- [Sample .csv file for WooCommerce product import](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/sample-data/sample_products.csv)

As you have already said, the first image is imported as a featured image and the others as product thumbnails (product gallery).

> The first image is certainly imported as a featured image.

If not for you, **make sure the url and image file name are correct**.

When you have to manage so many images you need to be organized.

I don't know how you handled the filenames but assuming you have 4 images for each product (where the first is the featured image) **you could use the product SKU as the image identifier**.
So if the SKU was `H451P` the image file names will be:

- `H451P.jpg` - *(featured image)*
- `H451P-1.jpg` - *(first image gallery)*
- `H451P-2.jpg` - *(second image gallery)*
- `H451P-3.jpg` - *(third image gallery)*

If the directory of your uploaded files is `/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/` then the filenames will be:

- `https://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/H451P.jpg` - *(featured image)*
- `https://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/H451P-1.jpg` - *(first image gallery)*
- `https://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/H451P-2.jpg` - *(second image gallery)*
- `https://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/H451P-3.jpg` - *(third image gallery)*

This will save you a lot of time and can import your product images automatically *(this approach assumes you want to add the same amount of images for each product)*.

> Note that if you set a wrong url, the creation or update of the
> product **will be skipped**.

This work will waste you a lot of time at the beginning but surely the image management will be more efficient in the future.

> Keep in mind that you can also manage images with any plugin available
> but you will always have to specify which image to set as featured and
> which as product gallery.

Only a good file organization can save you.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly response...

There is no problem with my CSV an all at the import process results as espected.

Unfortunatelly, is not an option for me, to rename and "organize" 4600+ images that were automatically downloaded and assigned to each (1000+) product.

By "reordering" the images at the CSV, was the first option that came to me... but it´s still crazy! I should "surf" my products at the website, check if I like the image or not... then locate each at the CSV, edit the file and reimport for update them!

Comment: I was looking for a "friendly" option, that IN CASE I found an image that I don't like (I know that they are aprox 50/60), I could do 3 clicks at the backend to change it ... something that seems SO BASIC and I can't believe it was omitted in WC!

Comment: To understand, can the same image be used for multiple products?

Comment: Anyway, the only alternative in my opinion is to manually edit the product images for each from the WooCommerce backend: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-product-images-and-galleries/

Comment: I do not think so ... except for some exceptions,- Each product has its own images (3-5 each) and the problem is just a matter of "order", which I can not handle, since to do it in a massive/bulk way (in the CSV, for example) I lose" visual "control of the files that I am handling ... and doing it "visually" from the product edit process, implies searching/choosing the image, from among more than 4600!

Comment: may be some plugin??... I'm looking at the edit product page, and can´t believe there is no way to select any of the images I'M SEEING RIGHT THERE... and simply choose one of them to set as "Featured image"! I want to cry! jejeje

Comment: In the "Product image" section you must first click on "Remove product image" and then "Set product image".  At this point the media library will open and you can select the image you want or search for it by name. If you want to use a plugin you will have to search online.

Comment: That´s exactly what I want to avoid... to search each image among the 4600+ that the "media library" contains! Anyway... I guess that´s all and there is no solution for this, even when it seems to be SO BASIC.
I was looking for some plugins with no luck... so, I will considere to do it by editing the CSV. which even when it´s a really hard way, at the end of the day will turn out to be the least painful  =(